# Laravel 5.6 Eloquent integrity constraint violation when saving quiz record

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm currently working on a quiz application with Laravel 5.6 and am having trouble with saving a new quiz record.

The two tables that are being inserted into are `quizzes` and `user_quizzes`. The `quizzes` table contains some basic quiz data such as:

- quiz_name
- quiz_description
- quiz_pin
- active

The `user_quizzes` table contains two foreign keys to reference which quiz belongs to a particular user.

- user_id
- quiz_id

The error is an integrity constraint violation when inserting into the `user_quizzes` table. It successfully inserts the `quiz_id` but the `user_id` is left as NULL. I am unsure how to ensure the `user_id` is also inserted as I'm using Eloquent.

The full error is:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'user_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `user_quizzes` (`quiz_id`, `user_id`) values (6, ))
```

I am making use of the `QuizController`, `Quiz Model` and `User Model` for saving the record. Here is my `store()` method in the `QuizController`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $validator = $request->validate([
            'quiz_name'        => 'required|max:30',
            'quiz_description' => 'required|max:500'
        ]);

        $quiz = new Quiz(
            [
                'quiz_name'        => $request->get('quiz_name'),
                'quiz_description' => $request->get('quiz_description'),
                'active'           => '0',
                'quiz_pin'         => '5555', // hard coded for now
            ]
        );

        $quiz->save();
        $user = new User;
        $user->quizzes()->save($quiz);

        return redirect()->route('quiz_host.dashboard.manage-quizzes')->with('quizCreated', 'Whoa ' . Auth::user()->username . ', you have created a quiz! Now it\'s time to add some questions');

    }
```

My `User` Model is a follows:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'username', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function activation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Activation');
    }

    public function profile()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Profile');
    }

    public function quizzes()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Quiz::class, 'user_quizzes', 'user_id', 'quiz_id');
    }
}
```

and my `Quiz` model:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Quiz extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'quizzes';
    protected $fillable = ['quiz_name', 'quiz_description', 'active', 'quiz_pin'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_quizzes', 'quiz_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Any guidance as to what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Create the user first, then attach the quiz.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `$quiz->save();` and `$user->quizzes()->save($quiz);` each insert a new record into the Database; and if that's the case, you would just omit the first `$quiz->save()`. Otherwise, save your `User` first and set the quiz's `user_id` to the saved user before you call `$quiz->save();`

Comment: Thank you both, I set the current user with `$user = Auth::user()` and then omitted the `$quiz->save()` and just left `$user->quizzes()->save($quiz)` and it now works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Reviewing your code

This is your controller:

**QuizController.php**

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // your validations.

    // Storing the quiz.
    $quiz->save();

    // User instance.
    $user = new User;

    // Storing the relationship.
    $user->quizzes()->save($quiz);

    // Returning the view.
    return redirect()->route('quiz_host.dashboard.manage-quizzes')->with('quizCreated', 'Whoa ' . Auth::user()->username . ', you have created a quiz! Now it\'s time to add some questions');
}
```

Now, the problem here is related to the `$user` object.

When you do this:

```php
$user = new User;
```

You are createing an instance of the `User` class, but this object isn't persisted yet into the database, what this means is that this object doens't have an `id` yet. You can confirm this doing `dd($user->id)`, this will return `null`.

That's why when you do this:

```php
$user->quizzes()->save($quiz);
```

It throws the SQL error, because you are calling a method to store the `$primaryKey` (`id`) of the `$user` object in the pivot table. But given that the `$user` object doens't have a primary key is trying to store a `null` value instead.

## Solution

Now, I don't really know what is your "use case", but I will assume that the `$user` is the logged-in one, so to relate properly the relationship replace this:

```php
    // creating a User instance.
    $user = new User;
```

with this:

```php
    // Logged-in user.
    $user = auth()->user();
```

This will use the auth facade to get the actual logged-in user and return the object. Given that is a registered user it will have a proper `id`.

### Alternative

If your use case is different and you will relate the quiz to a different user, do this instead:

```php
    // Some other user
    $user = User::find($someId); // $user = User::find(5); for example
```

or this, to create a completely new `User` instance and relating a quiz to it:

```php
    // A new User
    $user = new User;
    $user->fill($someData);
    $user-save(); // this will assign a primary key (id) to the object.
```

Now you can attach the related model to it.

---

## Side note

Your `users m--------m quizzes` is a [many to many relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

So, as [the documentation says](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships), the proper way to store a relatioship between the two objects is the `attach()` method:

```php
    $user->quizzes()->attach($quiz->id);
```

This method will create a record in the intermediate table (pivot) with the ids of the `$user` and `$quiz` objects.

Answer (score 0):

To make it clear, `new User` will only create user model object, it is still not committed to DB.

When we try to call `$user->quizzes()->save($quiz)` it is will try to add an entry in user_quizzes pivot table, but user_id is empty, because user is still not created.

So you have to create a user entry in DB by calling `$user->save()` before adding it to pivot table.

```
    $quiz->save();
    $user = new User;
    $user->save();
    $user->quizzes()->save($quiz);
```